# getting started with chart controls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, charts

what are the good resources for getting started with  data visualisation chart controls in mvc for a complete beginner to chart controls...

tried some resources but they are not much helpfull, also any free pdf's will be helpfull

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11001

Instructions

1.Download DataVisChartControl.exe and save it to your local computer.

2.After downloading completes, double-click the self-extracting .exe file to extract its contents, DataVisChartControl.chm.

3.Open DataVisChartControl.chm to view the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[Telerik](http://www.kendoui.com/dataviz.aspx) have some visualization controls and even have server side helpers for ASP.Net MVC for them.

Another option is [Dojo](http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/) which is completely free to use.

Comment: im not supposed to use any 3rd party controls